# OpenCart - My VAT calculating is wrong

Tags: opencart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp9IY.png)

See picture.

If Total is 100 than subtotal is 80 + VAT 20 = Total 100. But here it shows product price is 100, VAT 25. VAT is 25% . SO it should be 20. Can I anyone help?

Comment: As this is your first question here, I want to kindly ask you to take the chance to ask a question with further information provided, so other people can understand your environment and attempts you have gone through.

Comment: what do you mean?